# Google BigQuery : transpose rows in columns

Tags: sql, pivot, rows, transpose

I know there are some threads opened already, but below is my request.
I want to put all items purchased by a customer from rows to column, key being the order_id.
Below is a sample of the data as I have approx. 1M rows.

**1) I want this :**

```
Row            |order_id         |sku    
1              |600007637        |M0532OCAL_M900_TU  
2              |600007637        |S9035OECD_M930_TU  
3              |600007613        |3SN002VMM_H000     
4              |600007613        |3SN171XGU_H860
```

**2) To become this**

```
Row       |order_id          |sku                     |sku2                 
1         |600007637         |M0532OCAL_M900_TU       |S9035OECD_M930_TU    
2         |600007613         |3SN002VMM_H000          |3SN171XGU_H860
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: Please tag you DBMS and post your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You can left join with `order_id` and another `sku`. then group it by order_id:

```
select TA1.order_id, TA1.sku, TA2.sku as sku2
from table_name as TA1
left join table_name as TA2
on TA1.order_id = TA2.order_id and TA2.sku != TA1.sku
group by TA1.order_id
```